# Magento 2 Install Module Fails

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

I have a completely fresh install of Magento 2.1.2 installed via Composer. I am attempting to install a module called "Advanced Content Manager 2" which is said to be compatible with Magento 2.1 and below.

My problem is that no matter what method I use, I can not get the module to install and every time it seems to completely break the Magento install, requiring a fresh re-install.

1. I have tried installing via the admin panels Component Manager. When I do this, the module shows as available, all readiness checks and backups succeed. However when I go to perform the install the console log gets stuck in a loop of seemingly enabling/disabling maintenance mode. Trying to recover from the backup always fails.
2. When I install via command line manually, as documented @ http://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/documentation/m2/general/installation-guide I only get `Unknown module(s): 'Blackbird_ContentManager'` as a response.

I have tried to manually move the module folder around within the project but it never appears within the command line request to list modules and installing always fails to find the module.

Can anyone point me to documentation that actually outlines the correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to install a module with Magento 2.

If you have purchased the module via the Magento 2 marketplace, you should to sign in into your Magento 2 component manager with your marketplace account credentials, then install the purchased module.
You can found the fully steps in the Magento 2 user documentation:
http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/quick-tour/install-extension.html

If you want to install manually the package from the marketplace, you have to rebuild the path of the module, here it seems to be : 'app/code/Blackbird/ContentManager/' or even : 'vendor/blackbird/contentmanager/'

If you have purchased the module from the developer website, try to contact their technical support.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the module in app/code or vendor folder whichever that module goes. Then run in your terminal: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

The list of installed modules will appear on your terminal. If the module name does not appear on that list then that means the module has no registration.php or there are missing files of the module.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the module to the vendor folder. I then ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` which ran successfully but the module did not appear in the full list.


The module folder does contain a registration.php file which contains the following:

`\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Blackbird_ContentManager',
    __DIR__
);`

What else could be missing that would cause it to not appear within the module list? Magento 2 seems so poorly documented, such a pain.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the folder structure of that module? If you put it under vendor the structure should look like this:

Comment: vendor/blackbird/module-content-manager

Comment: That is case sensitive. If your folder structure does not look like this then you should put it on app/code. Here your folder structure should look like this: app/code/Blackbird/ContentManager

Comment: The folder structure does not match the vendor/blackbird/ so I just tried adding it to app/code (had to create the code folder). Added it there, ran the upgrade command through the CLI and still nothing appeared. I reached out directly to the developer for more help and will see what they say. I am also going to try to install another (free) extension to see if any will install at all.